# Why the image is black with no emission

Tags: materials

With the image node setup with Node wangler addon. Im trying to add emission to the texture. I mix with the node but the image got black & white and there is no emission to the texture. I plug the color of texture to Principle BSDF. Yet to same result Black & White. Whats wrong with my nodes. Any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: Just a note, but PrincipledBDSF has an input for Emission. So the Mix shader isn't necessary.